# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't recognize monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, monitor

So Ubuntu was installed (by our IT guy) while it was hooked up to a Dell 22" monitor.  It misidentified it as this:

[Displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt0zk.png)

The misidentification persists when I connected to my to my 4k, 43" monitor and the Dell 22" is no longer connected.  The new 43" monitor has the proper resolution and things seem to be working properly, but I'm worried that whatever confusion is the source of this will also prevent me from adding a second monitor when the time comes, a problem many others have had.  How do I get Ubuntu to see the monitor actually connected to the computer?  Using nVidia drivers 387.34.

Update: The problem persists after purging nvidia drivers, installing Cuda, and reinstalling 387.  I've also updated this to reflect new information that the original monitor was not a Goldstar 27", either.

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to talk to your IT guy, or is it just that you would rather learn more about Ubuntu yourself?

Comment: Oh lol I've told him, he has no idea either.  And actually "Goldstar 27"" may not even refer to the monitor he used either.

Comment: As long as the resolution is correct, how the system identifies the monitor is meaningless and depends on what and how the monitor reports itself. Sometimes the brand/model match, other times it matches the OEM code; sometimes it identifies the actual panel manufacturer and other times it presents something I have no idea where that come from. Sizes are often wrong because many use the same controller chip for different form factors. Again, meaningless, don't worry about it.